# How to make a link private in master node that can not be access by child node in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel-4

I am working with a small project on laravel 4.2. I want to extends master layout in a child node but i don't want to get access of all the js file of master layout in child node.

I want to limit the access of js file from master page.

Because the master layout's js file make conflict with child node js file and the js file of child node do not work if i extend's some js file from master layout.

For Example: I have two js file in master file

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('master/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('master/js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
```

If i extend's the master file with this two js file then the child node's js

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Do not work.

So I want get access of the following js file only

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('master/js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will also need jquery on the child template for bootstrap.js to work.

Best practice is to create a yield (header) and yield (footer) on the master template.

Then in your child template you can overwrite each section and add specific css to header or js to footer.

Edit: When overwriting the sectio heade or footer, use blade's parent () to append new scripts to the existing ones